# Adding select fields dynamically and validation in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am adding select fields using VueJS & it's working fine, but I want to add validation.

If the user selects `8mm` in the first select then `8mm` will disabled in other select tags.

### Here is HTML & Vue JS code

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="(input,k) in inputs" :key="k">
    <select v-model="input.thickness" name="thickness-`${k}`" class="basicRate block w-full p-3 mt-2 text-gray-700 bg-gray-200 appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-300 focus:shadow-inner" required>
        <option disabled selected value> -- Select thickness -- </option>
        <option value="8">8mm</option>
        <option value="10">10mm</option>
        <option value="12">12mm</option>
        <option value="16">16mm</option>
        <option value="20">20mm</option>
        <option value="25">25mm</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="input.qty">
    <span>
        <i class="fas fa-minus-circle" @click="remove(k)" v-show="k || ( !k && inputs.length > 1)"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-plus-circle" @click="add(k)" v-show="k == inputs.length-1"></i>
    </span>
</div>

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        inputs: [
            {
                thickness:'',
                qty: ''
            }
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        add(index) {
            this.inputs.push({ thickness: '', qty: '' });
        },
        remove(index) {
            this.inputs.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

[image: Screenshot of selects]

As you see the first two drop-downs have the same value meaning the user can select the same values. I'm looking for simple validation where if the user selects some option then he or she won't select the same value in other dropdowns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array of each selects' value. Just update the array whenever the `change` event is fired and conditionally add the `disabled` attribute based on these values:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    thicknesses: [],
    inputs: [{
        thickness: '',
        qty: ''
      },
      {
        thickness: '',
        qty: ''
      },
      {
        thickness: '',
        qty: ''
      },
      {
        thickness: '',
        qty: ''
      },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    handleChange(e) {
      this.thicknesses = [...this.$refs.selects.children].map(select => {
        return select.children[0].value;
      })
    },
    add(index) {
      this.inputs.push({
        thickness: '',
        qty: ''
      });
    },
    remove(index) {
      this.inputs.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" ref="selects">
  <div class="form-group" v-for="(input,k) in inputs" :key="k">
    <select v-model="input.thickness" name="thickness-`${k}`" required @input="handleChange($event)">
      <option disabled selected value> -- Select thickness -- </option>
      <option value="8" :disabled="thicknesses.includes('8')">8mm</option>
      <option value="10" :disabled="thicknesses.includes('10')">10mm</option>
      <option value="12" :disabled="thicknesses.includes('12')">12mm</option>
      <option value="16" :disabled="thicknesses.includes('16')">16mm</option>
      <option value="20" :disabled="thicknesses.includes('20')">20mm</option>
      <option value="25" :disabled="thicknesses.includes('25')">25mm</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But when I add a field with 10mm and add another with 25mm and delete that 10mm which I added earlier then 10 mm is disabled permanently for all the select fields.
how to overcome with this bug.

Comment: Oh, you could use a method which assigns an array with each selected value. See my edit